# OmSimulator With Python (How to disable the output file update on OmSimulator Python)

Tags: openmodelica

I am using OMSimulatorPython commands to run the OpenModelica FMU in Python environemnt. I am calling stepUntil method inside Python loop. I am not using the output file (.mat) that is created by OMSimulator. Is there any way to disable the output file creation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call `oms.setResultFile("model", "")` with an empty string as filename. That will disable the creation of the result file.